# I cannot change / delete a shortcut. - Shortcut Cycle in Select Box "W"

Tags: shortcut

I need to use hotkey "W" for an addon (Pie menu editor). But "W" is bound to Select Box, Shortcuts Cycle.
I can go in and change the Shortcut for "Select Box" but not the Shortcut Cycle. - Where can I find this shortcutkey? / Where can I delete this shortcutkey.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely, Peter[image]

Comment: I think it's under Preferences > Keymap >3D View > Set Tool by Name (wm.tool_set_by_id). I just changed it successfully to the Page Up key there although it then disappeared from the keymap view and I had to get it back by using Reset on the 3D View setting.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I solved it inside the Pie Menu Editor. Here it is possible to set up which shortcuts are to be overridden.

Comment: Glad to hear that you're sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it inside the Pie Menu Editor. Here it is possible to set up which shortcuts to be override.